# Entity Framework - same foreign key in multiple field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have 2 tables:

Cities

```
cityId
CityName
```

Employees

```
EmpId
Name
BirthCity - foreign key - cityid
LivingCity - foreign key - cityid
```

How can I use the same CityId twice in the `Employee` table as foreign key using Entity Framework with a code-first approach?

Comment: Pls show us what you have done so far.

Comment: I have tried many ways what I found by googling but nothing is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: And what are you expecting now? I am really really sorry but it is not a free coding site. We can' t create  the whole  db context code for you. We can only help if you have some errors. Try to create what you can . Create all properties and so on.  Only after this  post your code and we will try to help you.

Comment: Looks like EF should be able to map this by convention. Again, show what you tried. We have nothing to go by. Two lists of properties, that's all. No classes, no EF version. No exception messages.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is two instances of a many-to-one. The Foreign Key is located on the Employees table.

For example: (Table)

```
EmpId
Name
BirthCityId
LivingCityId
```

You can declare the FK properties and wire them up via attributes or configuration, or configure them via shadow properties (recommended)

Wired up with attributes:

```
[Table("Employees")]
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int BirthCityId { get; set; }
    public int LivingCityId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BirthCityId")]
    public virtual City BirthCity{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LivingCityId")]
    public virtual City LivingCity{ get; set; }
}
```

Using shadow properties via configuration (Either modelBuilder {below} or `EntityTypeConfiguration`)

EF Core:

```
[Table("Employees")]
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // No FK declarations.

    public virtual City BirthCity{ get; set; }
    public virtual City LivingCity{ get; set; }
}


modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>(e =>
{ 
    e.HasKey(x => x.EmpId);
    e.Property(x => x.EmpId).HasDatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerated.Identity); // For DB managed identity column..
    e.HasOne(x => x.BirthCity)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey("BirthCityId");
    e.HasOne(x => x.LivingCity)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey("LivingCityId");
});
```

EF6 can manage Shadow Properties as well via `.Map(x => x.MapKey()`

When it comes to code-first: If you declare your entity without wiring a FK up, EF will assign a shadow property for both of the cities based on the navigation property type. The table would most likely end up with something like City_Id and City1_Id for the BirthCity and LivingCity respectively. (EF convention uses the "type" rather than the property name)

I recommend using shadow properties for FKs to avoid situations where there are two sources of truth for a relationship within the entity. (Some code may rely on `employee.BirthCityId` while other code uses `employee.BirthCity.CityId`. Changing a FK property value can have different effects on an entity depending on whether the related entity is eager loaded or not so it is generally better to just use the navigation property and "hide" the FK.